# 2012: rails 3.2 Building subscription based application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, saas

Anyone could suggest an up2date subscription based application based on rails 3.2?
I need something like base camp login.app.ltd, signup.app.ltd with the basic structures layout out like protecting data from several users flowing in each other accounts.

It seems incredible hard to find a good starting point on this, 
anyone with some info good code examples please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very generic question, but have you looked at Devise?

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

It has a list of sample applications where you can see how it's used here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Example-Applications

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but my [SaaS Rails Kit](http://railskits.com/saas/) provides exactly what you want.

Comment: Hmm, hiring a regular rails developer @ 100/hr to build what SaaS Rails Kit provides. I'm not sure you'd get thru explaining what the different types of subscription you wanted and the gateway you wanted to use before you hit the 2.5 hour mark.